# jquery dialog closes immediately wheb called in Data Form Web Part

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I have a data form web part that includes this line:

```
<input id="btnAcceptPopup" type="button" value="OK" name="btnFormAction" onclick="javascript: 
if (showDialog()) return false; {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect=  
{http://domainNane/Pages/Home.aspx}')}" />
```

The intent is to show a dialog popup after user has entered data, and redirect to home page. but the dialog displays for a split second and closes

Here is the javascript:

```
function showDialog(){
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog(
{
    autotOpen:false,
    width: 348,
    height: 98,
    modal:true,
   buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
        },              
            modal:true,             
});
return false;
   }
```

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form, the browser is basically navigating to a new page. Obviously this means the current page is going to be replaced - and that includes the popup dialog which is  part of the page.

If you want the dialog to show after the form has submitted, then you should pop it up on the result page, not the form page.

If you want the dialog to show immediately, be visible while the form is submitting, and remain visible afterwards, then you're going to have to manually submit the form data via an ajax call of some sort.